# PHPWord - Adding HTML lists to .docx

Tags: php, phpword

I'm using PHPWord to generate .docx files from HTML.
In my HTML file I've the following situation:

```
<ul><<li><span>test</span></li></ul>
```

When I execute the conversion, it shows an empty area.
I tried to add the SPAN in parseChildNodes() method:

```
 $cNodes = $node->childNodes;
        if (count($cNodes) > 0) {
            foreach ($cNodes as $cNode) {              
                // Added to get tables to work                    
                $htmlContainers = array(
                    'tbody',
                    'tr',
                    'td',
                    'p',
                    'span'

                );
                if (in_array( $cNode->nodeName, $htmlContainers ) ) {                        
                    self::parseNode($cNode, $element, $styles, $data);
                } else{                    
                    // All other containers as defined in AbstractContainer
                    if ($element instanceof AbstractContainer) {                        
                        self::parseNode($cNode, $element, $styles, $data);
                    }
                }  
            }
        }
```

But it doesn't work... It still shows a blank area.
How can I show the SPAN content inside the LI list item?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what version of phpword are you using? And is your HTML file definition exactly like that or do you have a typo in the question (i.e. there is an additional '<' after the first <ul>)? 

Adding a span inside list item seemed to work just fine with phpword 0.13.0 version

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, yes, it's a typo in the question.
I'm using the version 0.12.0.
I'll try to update the library.

Comment: My friend, I updated the library but I got the same results. I have this list:
<ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;" type="a">
<li>
<p><span>I'm inside a SPAN that is inside the P</span></p>
</li>
<li>
<p>I'm inside the P tag</p>
</li>
<li>I'm directly inside the LI tag</li>
<li><span style="color: #f00; font-size: 10pt;">I'm just inside the span</span></li>
</ol>

it doesn't render the content inside a tag that is inside the <li> just the content which is directly inside the <li>

Comment: You are right, I was too hasty. The list items are indeed handled separately from other html containers and they cannot contain any tags inside (span, p, etc)...

Comment: Is there a way of modify this behavior (make it support the other tags inside)? Unfortunately, I can't change this structure. Do you have time for a possible job? :D

Comment: :) thanks for the offer - but I'm quite short on that time thing atm. There were already some todo comments on the latest code about merging the list item handling with normal node handling - i.e. you might be able to tempt some of the developers to look further into that. What should your result look like? I mean, addHtml doesn't seem to do anything with the inline styles so the spans result in normal text (when not inside list item that is), i.e. to have effectively the same result within you list items, you could just strip the span tags from your text when generating your document

Comment: oh, I understand. Thank you very much for your patience and I'm sorry for my replies in the comments, I can't open a chat yet. I'll try to strip the span tags.